# Can I define two recursive functions simultaneously in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have to functions f, and g with known initial values for f(1), and g(1) and their subsequent values are obtained trough iteration according to:  f(n+1)=f(n)\cos(g(n))-g(n)\sin(g(n)) and g(n+1)=f(n)\cos(g(n))+g(n)\sin(g(n)) . I have been trying to solve this in R using:

```
N=100 
for(n in 1:N)
{
 f=function(n)
 g=function(n)
if(n == 1) {
f(1)=0.8
g(1)=0.6} else {
  f(n)=f(n-1)cos(g(n-1))-g(n-1)sin(g(n-1)
   g(n)=f(n-1)cos(g(n-1))+g(n-1)sin(g(n-1))
 }
```

However, this is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that the following answers the question. But here are some errors in the code:

1. The functions are defined in the `for` loop.
2. None of the two functions is ever called.

My best guess is

```
f <- function(n){
  if(n == 1){
    0.8
  }else{
    f(n-1)*cos(g(n-1))-g(n-1)*sin(g(n-1))
  }
}
g <- function(n){
  if(n == 1) {
    0.6
  } else {
    f(n-1)*cos(g(n-1))+g(n-1)*sin(g(n-1))
  }
}

N <- 10
y <- numeric(N)
for(n in 1:N) {
  y[n] <- f(n)
  cat(y[n], "\n")
}
y
```

Comment: that indeed works, thanks! Problem with this specification is that it is relatively slow for high values of N.

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez Yes, so I've noticed. The number of function calls grows exponentially and they keep repeating what was already computed.